# R help options - setting help_type="text" for good

Tags: r

How to set for good parameter help_type="text" in R ? Have I to type command options(help_type="text") every time I start R session, or could it be setted as constant ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put that option choice in a `.Rprofile` file in the directory in which you start R. I use that method to load frequently used functions and a default set of packages.

I suppose I should mention that files beginning with a period (so-called dot-files) are sometimes hidden by the OS. (I know this to be true on Macs and Windows boxes.) On a Mac you can change the behavior of the Finder.app to display these files. That means you can use your OS GUI to edit them. (Not all of us are Emacs-capable.)

Comment: Yes, see `help(Startup)` for the options to customize your R session.